# Bootstrap form not coming out as expected

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This is my bootstrap code:

```
<form clas="form-horizontal" roles="form" name="login" action="submitticket.php" method="post" accept-charset="uft-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Title</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="" required maxlength="100" required>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="description">Description</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="255">
                </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label" for='category'>Category</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
                  <select class="form-control" name="category">
                <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                <?php
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT cat_name FROM Category");    
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                echo "<option value='".$row['cat_name']."'>".$row['cat_name']."</option>";
                            }
                            ?>      
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label" for='urgency'>Urgency</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
                  <select class="form-control" name="urgency">
                <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
                <?php
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT urg_name FROM Urgency"); 
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                echo "<option value='".$row['urg_name']."'>".$row['urg_name']."</option>";
                            }
                            mysql_close($con);
                            ?>  
                  </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $myusername; ?>">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Ticket</button>
              </div>
            </div>
    </form>
```

It is not coming out as expected.  The labels for everything, but the title field appear to be on the "previous" line i.e. the "Description" label appears to the right of the title text box, the "Category" label appears to the right of the description textarea and "Urgnecy" appears on the right of the category drop down.  How do I remedy this.  It isn't happening on any of my other forms and I think it has something to do with mixing the different types of fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"
```

You have a typo here:

```
<form clas="form-horizontal"
```

And style your form in this way:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```